# При добавлении ошибка "Value cannot be null " EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что не так с моим кодом добавления данных в базу?
   Мои модели для того, чтобы можно было отображать и вводить данные сразу по двум моделям создала специальный класс.

```
public class Owner
{
    [Key]
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string YearofRelease { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
public class CarOwner
{
    public int CarOwnerID { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Вот мой код для метода добавления, что здесь не так?

```
 public ActionResult Create(CarOwner owner)
    {                      
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Owners.Add(owner.Owner);
            owner.Owner.Cars.Add(owner.Car);
            db.Cars.Add(owner.Car);
            db.CarOwners.Add(owner);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code."Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity"

Вот отображение странички

```
@model CarOwner_2.Models.CarOwner

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Owner</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner.Birthday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner.Birthday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner.Experience, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner.Experience, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner.Experience, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Car.Model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Car.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Car.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Инициализация базы данных

```
       public class CarOwnerInit : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CarOwnersContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(CarOwnersContext context)
    {
        Owner ow1 = new Owner { Name = "Sam", OwnerID = 1, Surname = "Lucky", Birthday = DateTime.Parse("1993-06-21"), Experience = 3 };
        Owner ow2 = new Owner { Name = "Nick", Surname = "May", Birthday = DateTime.Parse("1994-04-06"), Experience = 5 };

        context.Owners.Add(ow1);
        context.Owners.Add(ow2);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Car ca1 = new Car { Model = "Alfa 146", CarID = 2, Mark = "Alfa", Type = "passenger", Price = 7, YearofRelease = "2001", Owners = new List<Owner>() { ow1, ow2 } };
        Car ca2 = new Car { Model = "Bentley 126", CarID = 4, Mark = "Bentley", Type = "passenger", Price = 77, YearofRelease = "2011", Owners = new List<Owner>() { ow2 } };

        context.Cars.Add(ca1);
        context.Cars.Add(ca2);

        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Сама база данных

```
public class CarOwnersContext : DbContext
{
    public CarOwnersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarOwner> CarOwners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем у вас эта строчка: `car = owner.Car;` ? Вы же теряете ссылку на только что созданный объект

Comment: Я убрала эту строчку, теперь ошибка при добавлении в базу вот здесь db.Owners.Add(owner.Owner);

Comment: А какая ошибка на этой строчке? Тоже `Value cannot be NULL?`

Comment: Да, вот полный текст ошибки An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code."Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity"

Comment: я добавила код инициализации базы. Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Почему у вас такая странная структура базы? Зачем нужна коллекция `CarOwners` если она дублирует m-t-m-связь между `Cars` и `Owners`?

Comment: Я хотела, чтобы там одновременно хранились записи о машинах и владельцах. Я думаю она там немного лишняя, но пока оставила, Вы думаете ошибка в этом?

Comment: не забывайте писать ник того кому пишите сообщение с символом `@` перед именем пользователя. я имел ввиду что свойство `Owners` класса `Car` у Вас скорее всего `null` отсюда и исключение при попытке добавить объект в коллекцию

Comment: @Bald, я добавила в  конструктор в класса Car такую строчку Owners = new List<Owner>(); но  ошибка так и осталась

Comment: Value cannot be null - Значение не может быть null. У вас CarOwner имеет поля Car и Owner которые не могут быть Null. Чтобы позволить это им используйте Nullable<T> но в вашем случае надо смотреть какая связь остается со значением Null.

Comment: @cvvvlad когда я написала эту строчку public Car ? Car { get; set; } сразу возникли ошибки 'System.Nullable<CarOwner_2.Models.Car>' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<CarOwner_2.Models.Car>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3):

по поводу структуры классов, если я правильно Вас понял то Вы пытаетесь реализовать связь [many-to-many](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php) между классами `Car` & `Owner`, я бы это сделал так:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие необходимые свойства
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners {get;set;}

    public Car()
    {
        Owners = new List<Owner>();
    }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие свойства

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars {get;set;}

    public Owner
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}
```

на основании данной структуры Entity Framework создаст соответствующую таблицу в БД, следующей структуры:

```
public class CarOwners
{
    public int CarId {get;set;}
    public int OwnerId {get;set:}
}
```

Работает это так:

```
using(var db = new DefaultContext())
{
    //Создаем машины, добавляем их в бд
    var bmv = new Car();
    var jaguar = new Car();
    db.Cars.Add(bmv);
    db.Cars.Add(jaguar);
    //и сохраняем
    db.SaveChanges();

    //создаем владельцев
    var owner1 = new Owner();
    var owner2 = new Owner();

    //Добавляем им машины    
    owner1.Cars.Add(bmv);
    owner1.Cars.Add(jaguar);
    owner2.Cars.Add(bmv);

    //Сохраняем владельцев
    db.Owners.Add(owner1);
    db.Owners.Add(owner2);
    db.SaveChanges();    
}
```

---

в `GUI` я бы сделал например так:

```
public ActionResult AddCar()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCar(Car model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //здесь добавление машины в бд
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

аналогичный методы для `Owner`

плюс метод

```
public ActionResult CarDetails(int carId)
{
    var model = //получение данных из бд
    return View(model)
}
```

в представлении я бы отображал подробную информацию о машине/владельце в нижней части выводилось частичное представление в виде таблицы с владельцами/машинами, плюс на странице `@Ajax.ActionLink` на метод который добавляет в текущую машину/владельца новую позицию

---

метод добавления машины владельца мог бы выглядеть например так:

```
public ActionResult AddCarOwner(int carId, int ownerId)
{
    using(var db = new DefautContext())
    {
        var car = db.Cars.Where(x=>x.Id==carId).Single();
        var owner = db.Owners.Where(x=>x.Id==ownerId).Single();
        car.Owners(owner);
        db.Entry<Car>(car).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("нужный нам метод");
}
```

т.е. в `gui` в выпадающем списке выбрали нужную машину/владельца отправили `ajax` запрос на сервер который сохранит изменения и вернет новый список владельцев/машин

Comment: А как мне создать метод create для контроллера и что передавать во view? Как сделать create только для класса Owner я понимаю, а как для двух классов сразу не понимаю

Comment: в методе для Owner я добавляю данные о владельце в базу по аналогии с тем, что Вы написали выше для Car, а как добавить машину в коллекцию в том же методе у меня ж нет данных о машине?

Comment: на странице работы с объектом типа `Owner`|`Car` завести выпадающий список в котором отображать существующие позиции, т.е. процесс добавления будет сводиться к тому что выбирается существующая позиции и добавляется.

Comment: @Ksu обновил ответ, добавил пример метода

Comment: большое спасибо, а без ajax никак нельзя сделать, потому что я вообще не знаю эту тему и в интернете нет похожих примеров?

Comment: @Ksu можно и без использования `ajax`, в это случае после добавления новой позиции делайте `redirect` на `Details`